# Set pixels on screen efficiently

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am using WindowAPI (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31437) to show a black full screen in matlab.
When drawing on screen, turns out drawing using line() and rectangle() functions is extremely slow.

How can I set values of pixels without going through matlab's mechanism? Getting the window's canvas for example would be great.

Comment: I assume this is a continuation of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7473686/97160). Can you post the code you are currently using?

Comment: If you haven't checked out [PsychToolbox](http://psychtoolbox.org/wikka.php?wakka=HomePage) yet, as was suggested in an answer to your last question, I highly recommend it. It does what you are looking for, and their code may be of use to you.

Comment: Code looks like this:

    rectW = 120;
    rectangle('Position',[1,1,1+rectW,1+rectW],'FaceColor','g');

I'd prefer to avoid the trouble of installing a new toolbox. My hunch is that there is a short elegant solution for this.

Comment: @Leo: please edit your question and add your code (preferably a minimum working example). Also it would be helpful to describe exactly what you are going to be drawing: disconnected points, lines, rectangles, or freehand drawings? There might be a way to avoid having to create many graphics option by using low-level functions like LINE and separate the different segments using NaNs for example...

Answer (score 3):

One way to imitate a "canvas" is by using a MATLAB image. The idea is to manually change its pixels and update the `'CData'` of the plotted image.

Note that you can use an image with the same dimensions as your screen size (image pixels will correspond to screen pixels one-to-one), but updating it would be slower. The trick is to keep it small and let MATLAB map it to the entire fullscreen. That way the image can be thought of as having "fat" pixels. Of course the resolution of the image is going to affect the size of the marker you draw.

To illustrate, consider the following implementation:

```
function draw_buffer()
    %# paramters (image width/height and the indexed colormap)
    IMG_W = 50;    %# preferably same aspect ratio as your screen resolution
    IMG_H = 32;
    CMAP = [0 0 0 ; lines(7)];    %# first color is black background

    %# create buffer (image of super-pixels)
    %#  bigger matrix gives better resolution, but slower to update
    %#  indexed image is faster to update than truecolor
    img = ones(IMG_H,IMG_W);

    %# create fullscreen figure
    hFig = figure('Menu','none', 'Pointer','crosshair', 'DoubleBuffer','on');
    WindowAPI(hFig, 'Position','full');

    %# setup axis, and set the colormap
    hAx = axes('Color','k', 'XLim',[0 IMG_W]+0.5, 'YLim',[0 IMG_H]+0.5, ...
        'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0 0 1 1]);
    colormap(hAx, CMAP)

    %# display image (pixels are centered around xdata/ydata)
    hImg = image('XData',1:IMG_W, 'YData',1:IMG_H, ...
        'CData',img, 'CDataMapping','direct');

    %# hook-up mouse button-down event
    set(hFig, 'WindowButtonDownFcn',@mouseDown)


    function mouseDown(o,e)
        %# convert point from axes coordinates to image pixel coordinates
        p = get(hAx,'CurrentPoint');
        x = round(p(1,1)); y = round(p(1,2));

        %# random index in colormap
        clr = randi([2 size(CMAP,1)]);  %# skip first color (black)

        %# mark point inside buffer with specified color
        img(y,x) = clr;

        %# update image
        set(hImg, 'CData',img)
        drawnow
    end
end
```

[image: screenshot]